# How to invoke all instance methods of a class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, selenium

I'm currently working on throwing together my own little test method runner script.

I need some way to call all of the methods in a class. When I invoke the `run_tests` method, my program is stuck in an infinite loop. What is causing this and what are some solutions?

```
class FadTest < SeleniumTest
  def can_open_page
    @driver.get(@base_url + "/")
    wait_element_present(:link, "DOCTORS")
    @driver.find_element(:link, "DOCTORS").click
    puts "page opened"
  end

  def test_method
    puts "it works"
  end

  def run_tests
    klass = self.class
    klass.instance_methods(false).each do |method|
      klass.instance_method(method).bind(self).call
    end
  end 
end
```

Comment: run_tests is instance method, and will call itself and hence create an infinite loop, can you move it outside of class?

Comment: Ah.. i should have thought of that! potentially.. Could I perhaps remove run_tests from the list, or I could also place it in the constructor. Actually, the class constructor doesn't work. I can look into doing it outside of the class, but would love to know how to remove a method!

Comment: Use `reject` to skip the method name? Write a `next if` in the `each` block that senses the method name? It's a simple loop and the normal methods of ignoring something will work.

Comment: `(klass.instance_methods(false)-[:run_tests]).each...` seems easiest. Another way would be to make `run_tests` `private` and invoke it with `FadTest.send(:run_tests)`, as [Module#instance_methods](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-instance_methods) only returns public and protected methods.

Answer (score 0):

[As mentioned by Wand Maker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32872948/how-do-i-call-all-instance-methods-in-ruby#comment53577507_32872948), `run_tests` involves recursion. Your code is being executed in the following manner:

1. Find the class of some object
2. Call `SomeClass.instance_methods.each {}`
3. Once you reach `run_tests`, you start the iteration over again.
4. Infinite loop -- you never reach the remaining instance methods.

I am not sure how you have designed your tests, so here are a few options to solve the problem

If all tested objects have the class `FadTest`, you can edit the logic within the iteration, my preferred solution is [what the Tin Man suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32872948/how-do-i-call-all-instance-methods-in-ruby#comment53577917_32872948)

```
klass.instance_methods(false).each do |method|
  next if method == :run_tests
  # ...
end
```

Only problem is that you are still scanning the `:run_tests` element. If you want to remain full proof and not have `:run_tests` in the array, you can try [what Cary Swoveland suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32872948/how-do-i-call-all-instance-methods-in-ruby#comment53578241_32872948):

```
(klass.instance_methods(false) - [:run_tests]).each {}
```

If the class of the tested object *is not* `FadTest`, then I would suggest a rewrite of the method.

```
def self.run_tests(object)
  klass = object.class
  klass.instance_methods(false).each {}
end

FadTest.run_tests(some_object)
```